# Can an Oracle IDENTITY column be nullable?

Tags: oracle, database-design, null, unique-constraint, identity

I want to create an `ID` column that automatically generates unique ID numbers by default.

Users won't be inserting rows via `INSERT` statements, rather, they'll create rows using an out-of-box [application](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing/a-quick-tour-of-editing.htm) (using the [attribute editing environment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/a-quick-tour-of-tables-and-attribute-information.htm)).

I've heard that auto-generated IDs can be achieved by creating an [Oracle IDENTITY column](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)
 (hint: to find the relevant section in the linked page, search for this text: `Use this clause to specify an identity column.`).

---

And so, I have successfully created a table with an `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE A_TEST_TABLE (ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY);
```

However, I see that the field is not nullabe:

```
SELECT ID FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'A_TEST_TABLE'

NULLABLE = N
```

This is a **problem** because my application tries to "do users a favor". If a field is not nullable, the application automatically inserts a zero as a dummy value. This **overwrites** the auto-generated ID (which of course, is not what I want). I'm guessing that it does this to avoid getting an error message from the database if a null value is committed.

To avoid this issue with my application, is it possible to make the field **nullabe**?

When I read the documentation, it says:

> If you specify ON NULL, then Oracle Database uses the sequence
>   generator to assign a value to the column when a subsequent INSERT
>   statement attempts to assign a value that evaluates to NULL.

Does this imply that an `IDENTITY` field can be nullable? If so, how?

---

*I recognize that I have no idea what I'm doing. I don't even think I would ultimately want an ID field that is nullable. I'm just trying to make sense of all this, and I'm failing.*

Comment: I don't think making it nullable will work. Even if it can be done, your app will start sending 0s and the second time (row) it tries, that the `UNIQUE` constraint will complain. (I assume you do have a unique constraint!)

Comment: "If a field is not nullable, the application automatically inserts a zero as a dummy value. This overwrites the auto-generated ID (which of course, is not what I want)."   could you make the identity columns as *generated always* so you never will want to insert/update the value? leave it to the db to populate it ?

Comment: @Raj : Good idea. `CREATE TABLE A_TEST_TABLE (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);`. Unfortunately, when I try to add a row to the table using the application, I get an error: `Database Row Change: An unexpected failure occurred. Underlying DBMS error [ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column][USER1.A_TEST_TABLE]`

Comment: @Wilson that is the whole point is you completely avoid populating the id column, i thought I made that clear in my comment. when identity column is defined as ALWAYS, you cannot update or insert into that column. This is a calculated safeguard. instead of identity column, could you have a pre-insert trigger and if the column value is 0 (helpfully inserted by application) or null, you replace that with a sequence.nextval ?

Comment: @Raj Ok, clearly I'm not understanding. I'll go back over this and re-assess.

Comment: @Raj To be clear though, when I got the error, I wasn't trying to manually update an `ID`. I was simply trying to create a new record. I think I got the error because the application tried to insert a zero into the `ID` field, which, now that I've specified it as `GENERATED ALWAYS`, it won't allow this.

Comment: @Raj And yes, I think I will opt to use a `sequence` and a `before insert trigger`, instead of an `identity` column. More info here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177432/100880 and in RDFozz's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the column NULLable, but not make it an IDENTITY column; instead, create a sequence, and an `INSERT` trigger that sets the ID value from the sequence. Prior to version 12.1, IDENTITY columns weren't available, and using a sequence was the workaround.

Comment: More info here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177407/trigger-to-get-next-prefixed-id-is-there-a-better-way