# Concatenate text and tochar(): Why is there a space between the two?

Tags: oracle

I want to construct an ID from a textual prefix and a number (more info [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177432/100880)).

For example, I want to concatenate `ABC` with `1`, while padding the `1` to 6 digits: `ABC000001`

However, when I try this, it puts a space between the two:

```
SELECT 
    'ABC' || to_char('1','000000') AS ID
FROM 
    DUAL;

Result: ABC 000001
```

Why does it put a space in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `to_char()` pads the result with spaces (I never understood why).

You need to use the "fill mode":

```
'ABC' || to_char('1','FM000000')
```

Comment: as per the documentation . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570  it's to provide room for the negative sign .. ;)   "Negative return values automatically contain a leading negative sign and positive values automatically contain a leading space unless the format model contains the MI, S, or PR format element."